# React Native setState issue using an Object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I don't why my setQuantity doesn't update the "quantity" variable using setState.
Inside the function the object is updated, but not the variable "quantity".

```
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState({breakfast: 0, lunch: 0, dinner: 0});

const onChangeQuantity = (value, type) => {
    let qty = quantity;
    qty[type] = value;

    //console.log(qty);  
    //{"breakfast": 0, "dinner": 0, "lunch": 6}

    setQuantity(qty);
  };
```

The console shows that the last change was 6 lunches. I have a console for "quantity" outside the function to see if changes, but only shows the init values (0, 0, 0) when the screen is loaded.

[image: Preview]

Can you please help me fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe your answer lays within the useState hook. The link will explain that update objects are not merged automatically. Please review the spread operator and useReducer sections. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Thank you for the reference.

Comment: Of course, happy to help. Glad someone solved it too for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same old error, you are mutating the state, don't do that. Always set a new reference to trigger the render with updated values

```js
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState({breakfast: 0, lunch: 0, dinner: 0});

const onChangeQuantity = (value, type) => {
    let qty = { ... quantity }; // make a copy
    qty[type] = value;
    setQuantity(qty);
};
```

Comment: @EzequielVillarreal Great, remember this. This will happen in case of arrays and any kind of object where you are not updating the reference

Comment: Cool.  I will never forget this. Thank you again.